# Automatic Spacing between labels

Tags: iphone, whitespace

How can we set automatic space between labels. The dynamic text is provided to the labels, and second label should auto frame itself, so that both are not over written. How can i achieve this. I need when first label text finish then second label starts keeping distance from previous. Please guide for the above.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
CGSize size = [firstLabel.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0]];
secondLabel.frame=CGRectMake(size.width+20,4, 9, 14);
```

For more info, chk this [Get length of a UIlable according to a string of diffrent length](http://programmingjugaad.com/get-length-of-a-uilable-according-to-a-string-of-diffrent-length/)

For getting image size

```
UIImage *tempimage= [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullImgNm];
Float width =   tempimage.size.width;
```

so your imageview frame will be

```
yourImageView.frame=CGRectMake(size.width+20,4,width, 14);
```

and your secondlabel frame will be

```
secondLabel.frame=CGRectMake(size.width+width+20,4, 9, 14);
```

Comment: I am having an imageview in between two variables can that be adjustable too.

Comment: you can set width of imageview using image width i.e image.size.width

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the `UILabel` frame using `constrainedToSize` propery .

```
CGRect infoRect = self.conditionLabel.frame;
NSString *fileName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"txt"]; 

NSString *textString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileName encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[self.conditionLabel setText:textString];
[textString release];

CGSize defaultSize = CGSizeMake(sectionWidth, 9999.0);
UIFont *defaultFont = kCCOpenSansFont(font, 14.0);

CGSize infoSize = [[self.conditionLabel text] sizeWithFont:defaultFont constrainedToSize:defaultSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

infoRect.size.height = infoSize.height;
[self.conditionLabel setFrame:infoRect];
```

Comment: I am having an imageview in between two variables can that be adjustable too.

Comment: Yes you can. you ca adjust frame 

CGRect imaeRect = imageview.frame:
imageRect.origin.y = firstlabel.frame.origin.y  + firstlabel.frame.size.height + 5;
imageview.frame = imageRect;